# Interpolate with lmfit?

Tags: python, interpolation, curve-fitting, lmfit

I am trying to fit a curve with lmfit but the data set I'm working with does not contain a lot of points and this makes the resulting fit look jagged instead of curved.

I'm simply using the line:

out = mod.fit(SV, pars, x=VR)

were VR and SV are the coordinates of the points I'm trying to fit.

I've tried using scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline and the fitted the resulting data but I want to know if there is a built-in or faster way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some data? What is wrong with `scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline`, why is it too slow?

Answer (score 1):

While you might be able to do the job with [scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html), you would basically be fitting to the fit you already did.

Instead you can use the components that are given to you already from your original fit. It's very trivial once you know how, but the lmfit documentation does not provide a clear case.

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y, _ = np.histogram(np.random.normal(size=1000), bins=10, density=True)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, y.size)

# Replace with whatever model you are using (with the caveat that the above dataset is gaussian).
model = GaussianModel()
params = model.guess(y, x=x)
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)

x_interp = np.linspace(0, 1, 100*y.size)
# The model is attached to the result, which makes it easier if you're sending it somewhere.
y_interp = result.model.func(x_interp, **result.best_values)

plt.plot(x, y, label='original')
plt.plot(x_interp, y_interp, label='interpolated')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built-in way to automatically interpolate with lmfit.  With a lmfit Model, you provide the array on independent values at which the Model should be evaluated, and an array of data to compared to that model.

You're free to interpolate or smooth the data or perform some other transformation (I sometimes Fourier transform data and model to emphasize some frequencies), but you'll have to include that as part of the model.